org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor does not exist
When trying to use snakeYaml and using the import org.yaml.snakeyaml.*;, I havebeen stuck at the error YamlGenerator.java:6: error: package org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor does not exist
I have tried a mvn clean install and have checked the dependencies in the pom file to ensure that it exitst.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
